# How to auto-update foreign key in child in unidirectional @OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a unidirectional @OneToMany @JoinColumn relationship between a parent having a list of children.

The primary key are generated by the database (IDENTITY / mysql auto increment).

When I insert a new parent with new children (all ids are set to null), the database is populated and the references are correctly set.

However, after insertion only the primary key are updated in the objects, the foreinKey are left to null. I have to clear the persistence context and do a find to retrieve a value with the correct foreign keys.

**Do we have a way to force hibernate to populate the foreign key in our memory model without doing it ourself ?**

I think it is the reponsibility of the ORM to do it like it is responsible for to set the ID value. I want to it to be done automatically so we won't forget to do it manually by doing setParentId().

I know the argument of there is no such relation in the object model because the parent own the list of child so the child doesn't the need the reference ID, but in our case we want it for consistency purpose. Why a find() model should return the foreign key populated while the freshly inserted one won't have them. It doesn't sound right to me.

(Also it is important for us to only have the unidirectional @OneToMany we don't want to have a @ManyToOne reference of the Parent in the Child (because our child doesn't need it, it just needs the parentId)).

```java
// main
var emFactory = buildFactory(); // Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ORM");
var em = emFactory.createEntityManager();

var transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
var parent = new Parent(null, 0, List.of(new Child(null, null, 10)));
em.persist(parent);
transaction.commit();

// just inserted, parentId is null
System.out.println(parent.children);

// using find() parentId will still be null
System.out.println(em.find(Parent.class, parent.id).children);

// If I clear the persistent context, the retrieved entity has the correct value...
em.clear();
System.out.println(em.find(Parent.class, parent.id).children);


// Parent
@Entity @ToString
public class Parent {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public int value;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public List<Child> children;

    public Parent(Long id, int value, List<Child> children) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.children = children;
    }

    private Parent() {
    }
}

// Child
@Entity @ToString
public class Child {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    Long parentId;

    int value;

    public Child(Long id, Long parentId, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentId = parentId;
        this.value = value;
    }

    private Child() {
    }
}
```

Comment: The child shouldn't have a parentId. This is the foreign key, and it's managed by the parent, since you have a unidirectional association. If you want the child to know its parent, then it means you should have a bidirectional association.

Comment: @JBNizet I didn't know hibernate could work without the forein key in the object. It now totally make sense, I removed it and my object is consistent. And yes you are right, if the child need the parentId it is a bidirectional association.